# matching panda dataframe and list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, matching

I have a dataframe df as follow

```
 Number   PT
     
    5        AA
    
    64       BB
  
    7        CC
```

Then a another list of objects,

```
myList = [{'label': 'AA', 'value': 'AA', 'group': 'A'}, {'label': 'BB', 'value': 'BB', 'group': 'B'}]
```

I want for every PT to have the associated group(when available) from the list, so the result should look like

```
    Number       PT    group
         
        5        AA    A
        
        64        BB    B
      
        7        CC    NOT_MATCHED
```

Comment: How about creating a second dataframe from `myList` then merge on PT and fill na with "NOT_MATCHED"

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'Number': [5, 64, 7], 'PT': ["AA", "BB", "CC"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

myList = [{'label': 'AA', 'value': 'AA', 'group': 'A'}, {'label': 'BB', 'value': 'BB', 'group': 'B'}]    

for i, row in df.iterrows():
  for item in myList:
    if item['value'] == df['PT'][i]:
      df.at[i,'Group'] = item['group']
      break
    else:
      df.at[i,'Group'] = "NOT_MATCHED"
```

Comment: I was hoping for a more straight/elegant way, without looping manually on the df rows

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
df['group'] = df.PT.map({tuple(i.values())[0]: tuple(i.values())[
                        2] for i in myList}).fillna('Not Matched')
```

Comment: this won't work, the group will have the PT label and not the group label